# LLVM: How to compile with debug symbols for Compiler-RT

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am writing Compiler-RT interceptor modules for LLVM, and I am encountering run time bugs. If I turn on debug symbols when invoking clang I get the symbols for the program clang is compiling. How do I get the debug symbols for Compiler-RT code? How do I know where the faulty interceptor code is coming from?

I have already tried building llvm, compiler-rt, clang, etc. in debug mode. This doesn't add symbols to compiled programs.

This is the build configuration command I am currently using:
`cmake -G Ninja -DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 -DLLVM_BUILD_DOCS=OFF -DLLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN=ON -DLLVM_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCOMPILER_RT_DEBUG=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/../llvm_install`

Comment: Have you tried this option with cmake "COMPILER_RT_DEBUG"?

Comment: -DCOMPILER_RT_DEBUG=ON does not cause symbols from Compiler-RT code to appear in compiler output.

Comment: My understanding is compiler-rt is built after clang, regardless of clang built in debug or release modes COMPILER_RT_DEBUG will make clang compile compiler-rt with debug symbols. COMPILER_RT_DEBUG "Build runtimes with full debug info"  -- This is the description of the flag from cmake file. Did you clean your build files before doing a cmake again?